# Specifying cacheDirectory in .babelrc file

Tags: babeljs

I tried:

```json
{
    "env": {
        "development": {
            "option": {
                "cacheDirectory": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it didn't work. I just want to enable the `cacheDirectory` in development environment for the faster hmr. any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`cacheDirectory` is actually an option of `babel-loader`, not `babel` itself, so the `babelrc` config is not the right place for this option.

You can enable it in the configuration of `babel-loader`. One way of doing so is by using `loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory'`.

From the [`babel-loader` docs](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader#options) (emphasis my own):

> This loader also supports the following *loader-specific* option:
>
> - `cacheDirectory`: Default `false`. When set, the given directory will be used to cache the results of the loader. Future webpack builds will
>     attempt to read from the cache to avoid needing to run the potentially
>     expensive Babel recompilation process on each run. If the value is
>     blank (`loader: 'babel-loader?cacheDirectory'`) or `true` (`loader:
>     babel-loader?cacheDirectory=true`) the loader will use the default
>     cache directory in `node_modules/.cache/babel-loader` or fallback to the
>     default OS temporary file directory if no `node_modules` folder could be
>     found in any root directory.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using babel-node - you can use

```
BABEL_CACHE_PATH=/foo/my-cache.json babel-node script.js

# or

BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 babel-node script.js
```

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-register#babel-cache-path